# How to find if $\lim_{n\to \infty} {n \over 3^n}$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {n \over 3^n}$$

I think this involves the comparison test? My thought was comparing it to $1 \over 3^n$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$0\lt \frac{n}{3^n}=\frac{n}{(1+2)^n}\le\frac{n}{1+\binom{n}{1}2^1+\binom{n}{2}2^2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**: For $n\geq 2$, we have
$$3^n = (1+2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}k 2^k > \dbinom{n}2 2^2 = 2n(n-1) \implies \dfrac{n}{3^n} < \dfrac1{2(n-1)}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For $n \geq 1$, $n \leq 2^n$.